# How can I get all of x values from what I think is JSON

Tags: json, python-3.x, discord.py

Python version: 3.10

Running a function returns this:

`[{'type': 1, 'components': [{'type': 2, 'style': 1, 'label': 'She/Her', 'custom_id': 'She/Her'}, {'style': 1, 'label': 'He/Him', 'custom_id': 'He/Him', 'type': 2}]}]`

How can I get all values of 'custom_id' within what is returned? Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried, and why doesn't it work? Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
myList = [{'type': 1, 'components': [{'type': 2, 'style': 1, 'label': 'She/Her', 'custom_id': 'She/Her'}, {'style': 1, 'label': 'He/Him', 'custom_id': 'He/Him', 'type': 2}]}]
for user in list(myList[0]["components"]):
    print(user["custom_id"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format your json here
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
to see, wich list is in wich :)

@[infinity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16496399/infinity) wrote it similar.

```json
[
  {
    "type":1,
    "components":[
      {
        "type":2,
        "style":1,
        "label":"She/Her",
        "custom_id":"She/Her"
      },
      {
        "style":1,
        "label":"He/Him",
        "custom_id":"He/Him",
        "type":2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

```py
myList = [{'type': 1, 'components': [{'type': 2, 'style': 1, 'label': 'She/Her', 'custom_id': 'She/Her'}, {'style': 1, 'label': 'He/Him', 'custom_id': 'He/Him', 'type': 2}]}]

for user in myList[0]['components']:
    print(user['custom_id'])
```